# Correct way to use "who" in an introductory sentence about a movie

Tags: word-usage

Today I wrote the following introductory sentence about the movie “Outsourced”:

> The movie “Outsourced” produced in the year 2006 and directed by John Jeffcoat deals with a part of a company being outsourced and Todd - the supervisor - is supposed to go to India to train the new employees.

But I was told that this was partially wrong as there was a word missing, and it should be like this:

> The movie “Outsourced” produced in the year 2006 and directed by John Jeffcoat deals with a part of a company being outsourced and Todd - the supervisor - **who** is supposed to go to India to train the new employees.

My question is which of the both is the correct one?

Comment: The movie “Outsourced” produced in the year 2006 and directed by John Jeffcoat deals with a part of a company being outsourced, and with Todd –  the supervisor –  who is supposed to go to India to train the new employees.

Comment: Great movie!  And what Edwin said, because if you remove all the superfluous parts of that sentence, you're left with this which makes it clearer: The movie deals with Todd, the supervisor, who is supposed to..."

Comment: @KristinaLopez Umm! Not sure I agree with you and Edwin. I think it is also grammatical, albeit with a subtly different meaning, when you omit the *who*. To simplify: *The play deals with an outsourcing; and Todd the supervisor is supposed to go to India*. The only thing of significance I have added is the semi-colon after *outsourcing*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Umm!

Comment: @WS2, actually, that's the way I read it the first time and thought "no who!" but then upon re-reading it, felt that the "who", in that sentence's current state (no semi-colon), the "who" is needed.  I agree wholeheartedly that with the semi-colon, no "who"!

Comment: 'The play deals with an outsourcing; and Todd the supervisor is supposed to go to India.' is colloquial; I'd say it attempts to coordinate the uncoordinatable. I'd want 'The play deals with an outsourcing, and in it, Todd the supervisor is supposed to go to India.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Now that we are into that level of analysis, I do have concerns over the *who version* too. *The play deals with an outsourcing and Todd the supervisor, who is supposed...* Who is Todd? What sort of chap is he? What does he supervise? These would seem as essential to me as *and in it*, which is an elision, provided by the further context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are gramatically correct. But only the second version conveys the intended meaning. Let's look at these two simpler versions:

> The movie deals with a company and Todd is supposed to go to India.
>
> The movie deals with a company and Todd **who** is supposed to go to India.

In version 1 the movie and what it deals with is totally unrelated to Todd. It's just two unrelated sentences stuck together. Version 2 however tells us that the movie actually *deals with Todd*. You could read my shortened
versions also as:

> The movie deals with a company. (And) Todd is supposed to go to India.
>
> The movie deals with a company and Todd (**who** is supposed to go to India).

Answer (score 1):

Either way it is a long and complex sentence; but it's grammatical both ways round, albeit with different structures, that may not be what you intend.

It's syntactically simpler without "who":

> [The movie “Outsourced” produced in the year 2006 and directed by John Jeffcoat deals with a part of a company being outsourced] and [Todd - the supervisor - is supposed to go to India to train the new employees.]

but, as you see, what you get is two separate sentences linked with "and", which don't coordinate well, as one is about the movie (and what it deals with), and the second is about a character in the movie.

If you add the "who", you get this structure:

> The movie “Outsourced” produced in the year 2006 and directed by John Jeffcoat deals with [[a part of a company being outsourced] and [Todd - the supervisor - [who is supposed to go to India to train the new employees]]].

So the object of "deals with" is the coordination of "a part of a company being outsourced" and "Todd - the supervisor - who is supposed to go to India to train the new employees". This is almost certainly what you mean; but I think it would be better cast as at least two sentences.